# VB.Net - Tidying up some code

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with a lot of LineShapes on it, and basically what I'm trying to do is make certain lines a blue colour and others a black colour, depending what it's in an array of integers. Each line is called line1, line2 etc. So if one of the values in the array is 3, then line3 would be coloured blue.

I have the following code to handle all the lines more easier:

```
      MeterArray = New PowerPacks.LineShape() {line1, line2, line3, line4, line5}
```

However, since I'm going to have about 50 seperate lines, this is going to look quite messy when I reach line50. So my question is, is there a tidyier way of handling these lineshapes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding the lines manually in the forms designer, consider adding them programmatically

```
Const N As Integer = 50

Dim _lines(N - 1) As LineShape
Dim _numbers(N - 1) As Integer

Private Sub frmLineShapes_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: Fill the _numbers array with values.

    For i As Integer = 0 To N - 1
        _lines(i) = New LineShape With { _
           .X1 = 5 * i + 10, .Y1 = 20, _
           .X2 = 5 * i + 10, .Y2 = 60, _
           .BorderColor = DirectCast(IIf(_numbers(i) = 3, Color.Blue, Color.Black), Color) _
        }
    Next
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    Me.ShapeContainer1.Shapes.AddRange(_lines)
    Me.ResumeLayout()
End Sub
```

Now you have the lines in an array and can access and change them later easily.

---

NOTE:

The shapes of the Visual Basic PowerPacks are not added to the form directly; instead, they are added to a shape container. You must have added at least one shape to the form in the forms designer for VB to add a shape container automatically to the form. If not, you can still add it programmatically.

```
Me.SuspendLayout()
Dim ShapeContainer1 = New ShapeContainer
Me.Controls.Add(ShapeContainer1)
ShapeContainer1.Shapes.AddRange(_lines)
Me.ResumeLayout()
```

---

**UPDATE**:

If you add the lines manually, you can still access the lines by their names

```
For i As Integer = 0 To N - 1
    Dim index As Integer = Me.ShapeContainer1.Shapes.IndexOfKey("LineShape" & (i + 1))
    Dim line As LineShape = DirectCast(Me.ShapeContainer1.Shapes(index), LineShape)
    If _numbers(i) = 3 Then
        line.BorderColor = Color.Blue
    Else
        line.BorderColor = Color.Black
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I added an example, which shows how the lines can be accessed by their name.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just wanting to make the declaration look nice, you can use the underscore character (_) to continue on the next line:

```
MeterArray = New PowerPacks.LineShape() {line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, _
                                         line6, line7, line8, line9, line10}
```

...and you can continue in that pattern all the way to 50.

This would take 10 lines of code, but I think this is quite a bit neater looking than 1 really long line.

Answer (score 1):

I take it the 50 rows are shades of a colour?  This will go black to white..It will also be easier to maintain being a loop (say you now wanted 150 lines?)

```
        Dim colours as new List(of PowerPacks.LineShape)
        Dim colourStep As Integer = 255 \ NumberOfSubLevels 

        For nextStep As Integer = 1 To NumberOfSubLevels 
            colours.Add(New PowerPacks.LineShape(colourStep * nextStep)
        Next
```